# appMessagesGetIsSupported is false for appMessagesGetIsSupported

Tags: ios, objective-c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am giving a client a bit of support on his iOS app, which has support for communicating with a Pebble App. The current version of my clients app on the AppStore works great, however he asked me to update to the newest SDK for Pebble; and so I did. 
However, I am experiencing some issues which I can't seem to solve.

I have, for now, removed all comunication the app does with its counter app on the pebble watch and am only calling the `appMessagesGetIsSupported` function. This, however, is done from the main thread, but that should not be a problem.

This is my code:

```
-(id)initWithAppUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid
{
    connectedWatch = [[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] lastConnectedWatch];
    [[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] setAppUUID:uuid];
    [[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Watch is connected");
    NSLog(@"Pebble name: %@", connectedWatch.name);
    NSLog(@"Pebble serial number: %@", connectedWatch.serialNumber);

    return self;
}

-(void)startRecivingMessagesFromWatchObserver
{

    [connectedWatch appMessagesGetIsSupported:^(PBWatch * _Nonnull watch, BOOL isAppMessagesSupported) {
        NSLog(@"Is App Get supported? %@", (isAppMessagesSupported ? @"Yes" : @"No"));
    }];

}

[...]
```

The method `startRecivingMessagesFromWatchObserver` is called when some rights have been checked in the app. 
My log shows the following:

```
2015-11-29 23:53:41.938 Debug[425:49385] Watch is connected
2015-11-29 23:53:41.938 Debug[425:49385] Pebble name: Pebble 6B1B
2015-11-29 23:53:41.938 Debug[425:49385] Pebble serial number: 3OU011******
[...]
2015-11-29 23:54:05.654 Debug[425:49385] Is App Get supported? No
```

So, the watch is connected and recognized by the app. Yet, it states that app messages aren't supported. What am I doing wrong?

The demo Golf app works fine and does state that App Get is supported, however that is for the Golf app implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to call the `run` method:

```
[[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral] run];
```

https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/migration/pebblekit-ios-3/